# Choose from various dates using date time picker

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xampp

This button filters the `datagridview` using `datetimepicker`.
What should I do if I want to filter it between dates?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server = Localhost; database = venuesdb; user id = root; Password = "
    Dim SQLDataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim DatabaseDatSet As New DataTable
    Dim Bindsource As New BindingSource        
    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query = "Select * From venuesdb.cost where EventDate  = ('" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "')"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        SQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand = Command
        SQLDataAdapter.Fill(DatabaseDatSet)
        Bindsource.DataSource = DatabaseDatSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Bindsource
        SQLDataAdapter.Update(DatabaseDatSet)
        MySqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    MySqlConn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: use SQL [BETWEEN](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php) you'll want to use the `.Value`, not `.Text,` property of your pickers and SQL Parameters as well.

Comment: Im quite new to this, can you give me an example or something

Comment: The link I posted has examples and everything  (your db columns will have to be actual date types as well).